# Docker + nginx to bypass CORS

Tags: nginx, docker, proxy, cors

I'd like to use nginx locally to bypass CORS in browser.
I'm having trouble with getting the request back out of nginx. How would I get it to call an address back in my own pc's environment/context after getting the request on localhost:5000.

My nginx.conf

```
server 
{
    listen       5000;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
      resolver 127.0.0.11;
      set $example some-website-with-cors.com;
      proxy_pass http://$example;


     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
   }
}
```

I'm building this and running `docker run -p 5000:5000 proxy:latest`

Nginx+docker wouldn't know how to reach `some-website-with-cors.com` back in my env. How can I tell it where to refer the request?

Comment: Maybe your local docker resolver doesn't know how to resolve anything else that the container names? Try `resolver 8.8.8.8;`.